# How to Merge Objects with same keys?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have JSON response coming from Node.JS API where Label values are same but other values like dd1, dd2 are different I am trying to **merge same label values in one object**, How could I achieve this?

```
   {
      "label": "Medium", 
      "dd1": "Cat A", 
      "dd2": "Non Cision",
       
  },
  {
      "label": "Medium",
      "dd1": "Cat B",
      "dd2": null,
      
  },
  {
      "label": "Tone", 
      "dd1": "Neutral", 
      "dd2": null,
      
  }
```

Above JSON Objects we can see Label are same in first two so, it should be merge and null values eleminated. like this

```
  {
      "label": "Medium", 
      "dd1": "Cat A", "Cat B" 
      "dd2": "Non Cision",
       
  }, 
  {
      "label": "Tone", 
      "dd1": "Neutral", 
      "dd2": null,
      
  }
```

TS Code -

```
var output = [];
  value.forEach(function(item) {
    var existing = output.filter(function(v, i) {
      return v.label == item.label;
    });
    if (!existing.length) {
      if (typeof item.label == "string") output.push(item);
    }
  });

  console.log(output);
```

Comment: You say that entries with the same label should merge but the way that you're showing the merge isn't valid. Are you expecting the strings to be concatenated or an array to be created. i.e. should `"dd1": "Cat A", "Cat B"` be `"dd1": "Cat A,Cat B"` or `"dd1": ["Cat A", "Cat B"]`?

Comment: Yes, entries with the same label should merge and it should be like `"dd1": "Cat A", "Cat B"`

Comment: That's not a valid structure though.

Comment: if it can be like `"dd1": ["Cat A", "Cat B"]` that will also helpful

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Typescript - this is just a Javascript answer but I'm hoping it might be helpful.

```js
const data = [
  { "label": "Medium", "dd1": "Cat A", "dd2": "Non Cision" },
  { "label": "Medium", "dd1": "Cat B", "dd2": null },
  { "label": "Medium", "dd1": "Cat C", "dd2": null },
  { "label": "Tone", "dd1": "Neutral", "dd2": null },
];

const merge_value = (key, current_value, new_value) =>
  (key === 'label' || !current_value) ? new_value :
    !new_value ? current_value :
      [].concat(current_value, new_value);

const merge_objects = (object1, object2) =>
  Object.entries(object2).reduce(
    (acc, [key, value]) => Object.assign(acc, { [key]: merge_value(key, object1[key], value) }),
    {}
  );

const mapped = data.reduce(
  (acc, item) => acc.set(item.label, merge_objects(acc.get(item.label) ?? {}, item)),
  new Map()
);

const res = [...mapped.values()];

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this?

```js
const cars = [
    {
        "label": "Medium",
        "dd1": "Cat A",
        "dd2": "Non Cision",

    },
    {
        "label": "Medium",
        "dd1": "Cat B",
        "dd2": null,

    },
    {
        "label": "Tone",
        "dd1": "Neutral",
        "dd2": null,

    }
];

function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
    return objectArray.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
        let key = obj[property]
        if (!acc[key]) {
            acc[key] = []
        }
        acc[key].push(obj)
        return acc
    }, {})
}

function sum(a, c) {
    if (a && c) {
        return a + ', ' + c
    } else if (a) {
        return a
    } else if (c) {
        return c
    } else {
        return null
    }
}

let object = groupBy(cars, 'label')
let arr = [];

for (const property in object) {
    arr.push({
        property,
        dd1: object[property].map(o => o.dd1).reduce((a, c) => { return sum(a, c) }),
        dd2: object[property].map(o => o.dd2).reduce((a, c) => { return sum(a, c) })
    })
}


console.log(arr);
```